# C# Attribute - Revalidate when relational object is modified

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes

I have a case where I in my project have activities, which can have a list of addresses, categories and other stuff.

In the site there is a requirement for the activity to have at least one address which is a "Visit address".

I have a ValidationAttribute (CheckStateAttribute) which triggers every time I make a direct modification of the activity. **But it does not trigger when I modify an address connected to it.**

```
[CheckState]
public partial class Activity
{
    public Activity()
    {
        this.Address = new HashSet<Address>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Address { get; set; }
}
```

An idea I have is to put the CheckState on the Address entity too (and of course make some changes to it), but since there are more requirements than just the address, it will not be a good solution to validate the activity from a lot of different entities.

Does anyone know a way to validate the entity "Activity" when any of its relational objects is modified?

Answer (score 0):

You would inherit from IValidatableObject and implement the Validate method like below

```
[MetadataType(typeof(SeasonMetaData))]
    public partial class Season : IValidatableObject
    {
        #region IValidatableObject Members

        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (this.StartDate.CompareTo(this.EndDate) >= 0)
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("The Season End must be after the Season Start.", new String[] { "EndDate" });
            }
        }

        #endregion

    }
```